# How to do multiline substitution using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a text file named "a6s" with multiple lines like this:

```
y
n
yyy
n
y
yyy
yy
y
yyy
n
```

I used this script:

```
$ sed -i "s/y$^y/ya\ny/g" a6s;
```

I want to insert between two "y" chars at ending of last line and the beginning of next line to output:

```
y
n
yyy
n
ya
yyya
yya
ya
yyy
n
```

Comment: (^_^)  Sorry, my English is not good! Thanks to Sundeep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`GNU sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) (full credit for this great solution goes to @Sundeep, thanks):

```
sed -i '/y$/ {N; s/y\ny/ya\ny/; P; D}' a6s
```

In order to work on multiple lines with `sed`, you have to use `N`, `P` and `D` commands:

- `{cmds}`: group of commands
- `/y$/ {cmds}`: executes the group of commands only if the line ends with `y`
- `N`: reads next line to the pattern space
- `s/regex/replacement/`: does the substitution, no need for the `g` flag
- `P`: prints the pattern space up to the first `\n` character (first line)
- `D`: deletes the pattern space up to the first `\n` character

My original solution that used unnecessary labels:

```
sed -i ':a; N; s/y\ny/ya\ny/; {P; D}; ba' a6s
```

---

I recommend checking out this great [grymoire.com](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51) tutorial on working with multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks to PesaThe and Sundeep.

Comment: Since you are only comparing at most two lines and the substitution command caters for two lines, perhaps `sed 'N;s/y\ny/ya\ny/;P;D' file` might be suffice?

Comment: @potong Yep, that would do too. `/$y/` only skips the commands if they are not needed :)

Comment: Thanks to potong. Your script is brief.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. When you try to do anything else with it you are using arcane runes that became redundant in the mid 1980s when awk was invented. With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{while(sub(/y\ny/,"ya\ny"));} 1' file
y
n
yyy
n
ya
yyya
yya
ya
yyy
n
```

The above simply does what it clearly says - loops through the input replacing every `y\ny` with `ya\ny` while there are `y\ny`s to replace.

Comment: @PesaThe Yeah, sed is great for `s/old/new` and before awk was invented you needed to be able to do a bunch of other stuff with it and unfortunately since it's just a stream editor rather than a programming language all of it's commands are cryptic single characters but that was 40+ years ago - time to let it rest... I really wish the GNU guys had removed all of that extra crap from it instead of adding even more crap!

Comment: Oh and by the way, what is the reason for using `while (sub...` instead of `gsub`? I suppose it's a portability thing?

Comment: @PesaThe this is similar to `sed -z ':a s/y\ny/ya\ny/g; ta'` (assuming input doesn't have NUL characters)... you can't use gsub here because once `y\ny` gets replaced, the second `y` won't be available for matching with next line..

Comment: @Sundeep so it wouldn't work correctly for `y\ny\ny` for example, got it, thanks :)

Comment: awk can do gsub() but remember that in any tool a string matching a regexp can't be part of the next regexp segment matched on that same invocation so `sed 's/yy/yay/g` won't change `yyy` into `yayay`, you need `sed 's/yy/yay/g; s/yy/yay/g'` to do that. So I could have used gsub() but it wouldn't have done every replacement, I'd need a loop or 2 invocations for that so I decided to go with a loop to avoid redundancy and when you have a loop, sub() works as well as gsub() and IMHO it's a bit clearer.

Comment: any tool --> any tool without lookarounds... `perl -0777 -pe 's/y\n(?=y)/ya\n/g'`

Comment: any tool --> any tool evaluating the regexp in question. The string `y` at the end of `y\n(?=y)` does not become part of the regexp match but I'm not sure how to phrase my previous statement to more clearly express that I'm talking about strings that are included in the regexp match other than just saying THIS regexp. I suspect the point is made though.

Comment: it is clear :) was trying to make a cheeky comment.. should've added `/s` or some smiley..

Answer (score 0):

Converting the inputfile to a line is not an easy solution: you need to process the file twice:

```
tr '\n' '\r' < a6s | sed ':a;s/y\ry/ya\ry/g;ta' | tr '\r' '\n'
or
tr '\n' '\r' < a6s | sed 's/y\ry/ya\ry/g;s/y\ry/ya\ry/g' | tr '\r' '\n'
```